# Android Studio won't open Projects

Tags: android-studio, compiler-errors, project

I recently uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio and cannot get any of my old projects to open. All my previous projects now read "no content" when I load them  in the program. What steps should I take to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Look like you delete your projects , can you see if they are available at AndroidStudioProject file ?

Comment: yes, they are still in the androidstudioproject file

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to open an existing Android Studio project, use 4th option in the welcome screen - "Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gardle, etc)". That should do.

Comment: when I tried that i was prompted with the error: "cannot find file"